# Generate a json schema without starting a server?

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-server

Is there a standalone tool to convert a modularized graphql schema to a json schema?

I have a graphql server using apollo-graphql and graphql-tools `makeExecutableSchema`. It follows the pattern described [here](http://dev.apollodata.com/tools/graphql-tools/generate-schema.html#modularizing)

```js
// schema.js
import { makeExecutableSchema } form 'graphql-tools';
const Author = `type Author { ... }`;
const Post   = `type Post   { ... }`;
const Query  = `type Query  { ... }`;

export const typeDefs = [Author, Post, Query];

export const schema = makeExecutableSchema({
  typeDefs: typeDefs,
  resolvers: { ... },
});
```

How can I create a `schema.json` form either `typeDefs` or `schema`?

---

I need a json schema to use `relay-compiler` or `apollo-codegen`. `apollo-codegen` includes this script to create a schema from a graphql server...

```
apollo-codegen introspect-schema http://localhost:8080/graphql --output schema.json
```

...but I want to create the schema, and run apollo-codegen, in an automated build. I don't want to create a server.

---

> I would submit this as an answer, but the question has been marked off-topic ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

The answer from @daniel-rearden pointed me in the correct direction. `makeExecutableSchema` returns a `GraphQLSchema` so one can use `graphql`'s `printSchema` and `introspectionQuery` to get json or graphql language representations of the schema.

```js
// export.js
import { schema } from './schema.js'
import { graphql, introspectionQuery, printSchema } from 'graphql';

// Save json schema
graphql(schema, introspectionQuery).then(result => {
  fs.writeFileSync(
    `${yourSchemaPath}.json`,
    JSON.stringify(result, null, 2)
  );
});

// Save user readable type system shorthand of schema
fs.writeFileSync(
  `${yourSchemaPath}.graphql`,
  printSchema(schema)
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's [graphql-to-json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-to-json). I believe that has a CLI tool to do just that.

Alternatively, you could write your own script and just execute it with `node`. You don't have to spin up a server to run a query, you just need a schema and you can run a query directly against it. You can check out an example [here](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/guides-babel-plugin.html#schema-json).

Comment: Okay, it looks like `makeExecutableSchema` returns a GraphQLSchema. Your example from [relays docs](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/guides-babel-plugin.html#schema-json) example will probably work.